# django: access version from setup.py

Tags: python, django

I have the setup.py defined this way:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup


setup(
    name='My project',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='',
    author_email='my@email',
    packages=[
        'package',
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    scripts=['package/manage.py'],
)
```

And I am trying to get version number rendered in my template. But can't find the way to extract it from this place.

Comment: put the numbers into `__init__.py` or anywhere in your project, and from there you can easily import it both to `setup.py` and in template too

Comment: Well in this case I will have to update it inside some strange file like  __init__.py for each release. Which seems to be strange :( also it looks like it's not easy to access it for setup.py (e.g. )
python setup.py --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
ImportError: No module named django.conf

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting something like `__version__ == '0.1.0'` within a file and updating it on release.